# How do I iterate over object literal array with jquery $.each() method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object, literals

how do I iterate over object literal array with jquery $.each() method?

In the chrome debugger, it comes back as "undefined, undefined".

Any help would be really appreciated. thanks!

```
    var links = [ 
                    { className : 'hover', url : 'http://www.yahoo.com' },
                    { className : 'hover-2', url : 'http://www.foxnews.com' },
                ];


    loopy(links)


    function loopy(obj){

        $.each(

            obj,

            function(){

                console.log(obj.className + ', ' + obj.url);

            }                   

        );
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
   $.each(
        obj,
        function(i, val){
            console.log(val.className + ', ' + val.url);
        }                   
    );
```

The `$.each` function parameter takes two arguments -- the index of the current item in the array, and the second is the actual current value of the array.

See the [API](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) for some more explanation and examples.

You can see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dhoerster/CW5mj/) to see it in action.

Comment: +1 for the explanation, If only people took the trouble of checking the jQuery docs first...

Comment: @Mrchief - and if only people wouldn't spam these questions by making comments like yours.

Answer (score 1):

I just wanted to offer a slightly modified version of David's response that will be a little more gentle on the DOM when processing larger objects.

Original answer (above):

```
$.each(
  obj,
  function(i, val){
    console.log(val.className + ', ' + val.url);
  }                   
);
```

This solution works, but it generates an entirely new instance of the iterator function for every property in the object. There's no need for that, and I think you'll find more stable performance in larger applications by declaring specific methods to handle that sort of thing.

Try this:

```
// Process a property in your link object
function links_iterationHandler(i, val) {
   console.log(val.className + ', ' + val.url);
}

// Traverse the link object and pass each result off to the method above
$.each(obj, links_iterationHandler);
```

This essentially does the same thing, but doesn't hammer on the DOM as much. It's not a big deal if you only have a few items in your object. But if you're dealing with a lot of data, like a big recordset loaded via Ajax, it will make a difference for sure.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I would try this:
$.each([52, 97], function(index, value) { 
  alert(index + ': ' + value); 
});

The first property is the index.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/